# Построение дерева на php

Tags: php, treeview

Существует база данных с информацией об узлах сети. У некоторых узлов есть дочерние узлы, а у тех в свою очередь могут быть еще дочерние.

Таблица со всеми выведенными узлами сети выглядит примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В первом столбце - сам узел, во втором - его дочерний узел.

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на основной узел открывалось дерево его дочерних узлов, и, если у дочерних тоже есть дочерние, то при нажатии на них - открывались еще деревья.

БД выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть у одного узла может быть много дочерних.

Помогите пожалуйста советом и направлением, с чего начать и как в общем грамотно это реализовать.

Comment: Вам фактически надо при получении очередного узла получить все записи с данным main_unit и что бы в той же записи была информация, что есть дочерние элементы (подзапросом в списке select основного запроса). А дальше при нажатии на развертывание узла через ajax вызываете ту же самую функцию, которая уже для дочернего элемента получает что в него входит

Comment: Когда-то делал что-то подобное, использовал этот плагин https://www.jstree.com/ Может пригодится